# Facebook News feed returing null

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have been having a bit of a problem lately with the Facebook News feed. I am using
$mynewsfeeds = (new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me/home'))->execute()->getGraphObject()->asArray(); to fetch News feed. It was working perfectly a week ago, providing 10 stories with next and previous values. But now its returning only one story. I have checked in facebook api explorer and its working perfect there. I have 'read_stream' permission and also long lived access token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed facebook development team... Hope this helps others too.. with same issue.....
:)
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/449167695235902/

Answer (score 0):

I submitted the same in facebook developers community and found out that its Fb bug...
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/449167695235902/

Hope this helps others too...with same issue